# How can I override an inherited container in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a base template like this.

**base.html**

```
  <div class="container">
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}
  </div>
```

The problem is in a few pages that inherit from it (i.e., extend base.html ) I don't want the outer container around the content. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change a bit your **base.html** template

```
{% block content_wrapper %}
  <div class="container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
  </div>
{% endblock content_wrapper %}
```

Then in your few specifics template you can override the `content_wrapper` block.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way as I see it is to create another base template that you extend. Perhaps calling it base-purpose.html. Another way could be to use the `{% include 'another.html' %}` tag. This might be able to solve your problem as well.

See the discussion between [include and extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863695/include-vs-extends-in-django-templates) on stackoverflow

Comment: I don't really want to do this as there would be a lot repeated in both base templates.

Comment: I added some stuff which might answer your problem.