# Djangocms template not showing up

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I have a basic DjangoCMS up and running.

base.html contains:

```
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

I also have feature.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load cms_tags %}

{% block title %}{% page_attribute "page_title" %}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        {% placeholder "feature2" %}
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron"">
        {% placeholder "feature" %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% placeholder "content" %}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I added the "feature2" placeholder in the above, and it correctly displays for editing on the site.

I then added  a new line to base.html:

```
 {% block base_logo %}{% endblock base_logo %}
```

and created a new file, base_logo.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block base_logo %}
    <div>
        {% placeholder logo %}
    </div>
{% endblock base_logo %}
```

I expected this to also appear on the site for editing, but it doesnt. I have added the base_logo.html to the CMS_TEMPLATES in settings.py and TEMPLATE_DIR is also pointing correctly.

What else do I need to do for Djangocms to pick up my new template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#template-inheritance).

You're trying to use two `{% extends %}` tags, which won't work. You should use the `{% include %}` tag for `base_logo`, because it seems you'd want to include this in many templates. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863695/include-vs-extends-in-django-templates) provides more info.

Comment: Thanks, had since solved the issue another way but good to know about include vs extend.