# Django template include overwrite <h1> tag

Tags: django

I have the following html files.

banner.html

```
   <header class="intro2">
        <div class="intro-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                       <h1>{% block banner %}Bannertest{% endblock banner %}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

test.html

```
{% extends 'banner.html' %}
    {% block banner %}
    Test
   {% endblock banner %}
```

I'm new to Django but I would expect the H1 title to be updated to say Test instead of Bannertest?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend your main html not to include
replace

```
{% include 'banner.html' %}
```

to

```
{% extends "banner.html" %}
```

more details here: [include-vs-extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863695/include-vs-extends-in-django-templates)

your full new html:

```
{% extends 'banner.html' %}
{% block banner %}Test{% endblock banner %}
```

Comment: please see my updates, I've aded all the HTML. Using extends gives me an error.

Comment: can't have two extends within the same html file.

Comment: i edit your question remove all from your test.html and put there new code

Comment: thanks, but that now does not include my banner.html.

Comment: sorry my typo - now fixed, try it

Answer (score 0):

For block overriding you must use `{% extends 'banner.html' %}` instead of `{% include %}`

So instead of making small fragments for include, like in php, standard approach is to make a full template, say `base.html`, when extend it in child templates.

`{% include %}` tag is better suits for widgets with parameters, e.g. `{% include '_form.html' style='light' some_param=some_value %}`