# Django; How to debug {% include '' %} tag within templates

Tags: django, templates, include

Sometimes I get an empty string returned for my include tags which is impossible, because I have some static elements in it.

This is happening sometimes in my productive environment. How can I debug such an issue?

For example my footer or header disappears in some cases (Which I include within my "base.html") which I can't reproduce.

Thx

Example:

## base.html

```
<html>
... 
{% include "subdir/_header.html" %}
...
{% block content %}
    <h1>Default Content</h1>
{% endblock %}

...
{% include "subdir/_footer.html" %}
</html>
```

## home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
   <h1>Home related Content</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

So if I load home.html my footer sometimes disappears. No idea why, no errors.

FOUND THE PROBLEM

A missing static file caused that kind of problem. Unfortunately I did not get an error.

Comment: "which I can't reproduce" its always hard to fix these kind of bugs. Does it happen on the same templates or is it completely random? 
maybe some problem with the "block content" tag or you could try "extend" instead of "include".

Comment: Your base html should be Extended and not Included... include is for small blocks of codes, like components... blog post, news, contact and that stuffs...

Comment: I gave you an example. I hope it makes it more clear. I know the difference between {% extends %} and {% include %}. I updated my post with an small example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact reason of this issue, but can you try with {% extends 'base.html' %}.

The difference between include and extends right here:

[{% include %} vs {% extends %} in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863695/include-vs-extends-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 0):

Your base html should be Extended and not Included... include is for small blocks of codes, like components... blog post, news, contact and that stuffs

base html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

{% include 'path/head.html' %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{% include 'path/footer.html' %}

</html>
```

other pages

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<!-- Content from each page -->
{% endblock %}
```

**Obs.: Include inside of includes dont work propely, you can get the data from first page in includes inside includes... for that i usualy use templatetags or context_processors, depending of your need.**

Use django-debug-toolbar to debug your entire application in dev environment, you can see the entire request and the includes that you want

https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Unfortunately the error is not happening on my debug environment.

Comment: The template is not rendering or you not getting data from models?

Comment: Look at my example above. If I render for example "home.html" then my footer is not there. I looks like django is ignoring my "footer.html" (sometimes).

Comment: sometimes in same page? or there one page that never renders?

Comment: Always the same page. Is this kind of problem logged within the django log files?

Comment: if always at same page, probabily is something wrong with that page, double check your extend, your paths

Comment: Found the problem, a static file is missing on my productive environment ... Really hart to determine

Comment: if you using external environment as Amazon S3, Webfaction or Google Cloud you r code wont be able to create the folder, so you have to do that manually or give the right permissions to your application do that