# In Django, how do I reference one template from another one?

Tags: django, python-3.x, templates, navigation

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have these two files ...

```
appname/templates/appname/base.html
appname/templates/appname/navigation.html
```

In my base.html file, I try and include the navigation template like so

```
    {% include "navigation.html" %}
```

However, when I restart my Django app, I get this error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /navigation.html
```

How do I reference my navigation template from my base template?

Comment: Have you tried adding the folder name which it is located under: e.g. {% include 'appname/navigation.html' %}?

Comment: Just tried taht.  That's the winner.  Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [{% include %} vs {% extends %} in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863695/include-vs-extends-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the folder name which it is located under: e.g.

{% include 'appname/navigation.html' %}